# when posting data with angular js. $POST giving wrong results

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs to post form data by below given code:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    var req = {
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'myurl',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data : {
            message : "shan"
        }
    }
    $http(req).then(function mySuccess() {
        alert("Clicked");

    }, function myError(response) {
        alert("Error");
    });
}
```

when doing `print_r($_POST)` on server side:

```
Array
(
    [{"message":"shan"}] => 
)
```

why this is happening as you can see that my header are properly defined for form data?

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

when trying below given headers:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

getting `print_r($_POST)` result empty:

```
Array
(
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try header

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
```

Comment: getting same result with this also

Comment: problem was that i need to pass data as string

Comment: data: $.param({message:"shan"})

Answer (score 0):

Refer this

```
var inputJson =  { message:"shan"};
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(inputJson);
var req = {
    method: 'POST',         
    url : 'xxxxxx',         
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: jsonData
}
```

Comment: when doing   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} getting $_POST empty

Comment: could you please send the request screen shots

Comment: try this JSON var inputJson =  { "message":"shan"};

Comment: when trying this getting empty $_POST

Comment: check my question i update it according to your comment

Comment: could you please share the link. is it possible i can access

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162567/discussion-between-shahneel-ahmed-and-venka-tesh-user5397700).

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am using `application/json` and its working perfectly fine.

```js
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope, $http){
  $scope.submit=function(){
    var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      data: { message:"shan"}
    }
    $http(req).then(function mySuccess(response){
      console.log(JSON.parse(response.data.data));
      console.log("Clicked");

    }, function myError(response){
      console.log("Error");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submit();"/>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: please post this data on to php script on server side and check $_POST array.problem is that at php side $_POST has not data in it